# Evaluate .......

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Evaluate
$$I=\inf_{f\in \mathcal{F}}\left ( \sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}\left | 1-f\left ( t \right ) \right |+\int_{0}^{1}\left | 1-f\left ( t \right ) \right |dt \right )$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the vector space of all continuous functions $f:\left [ 0,1 \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\left ( 0 \right )=0$
I had only one idea to consider a continuous function and that's it ...
How can you decide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We first note that
$$
\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}| 1-f(t)| \geq 1
$$
if $f\in\mathcal{F}$, for $f(0)=0$. On the other hand,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}| 1-f(t) |\,dt 
$$
can be made arbitrarily small in $\mathcal{F}$: given $0<\epsilon<1$, define the function $f_{\epsilon}(t)=\frac{t}{\epsilon}$ for $0\leq t\leq \epsilon$, and $f_{\epsilon}(t)=1$ otherwise; then
$$
\int_{0}^{1}| 1-f_{\epsilon}(t) |\,dt = \int_0^{\epsilon}\left(1-\frac{t}{\epsilon}\right)dt = \frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon.
$$
Since
$$
\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}| 1-f_{\epsilon}(t)| = 1,
$$
it follows that $I=1$.